# Weird options menu -button in navigation bar (Android 4.0)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

What is this options menu button and how I can get rid of it?

See image

[image]

Comment: Its **Action overflow button for legacy apps**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its the legacy button. Newer phones don't have a menu button but obviously older apps still want to use it. This is the soft button that is used instead of the old hard button

You can read more about it here

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: Yes, thanks! I would vote up but unfortunately can't due to low rep.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default "more options" button.

Comment: But there's "More options" button also in action bar? Why two buttons? where this is coming from?

Comment: @ooxio must check: [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)

Comment: @cik but my device running on android 4.0.4 have no soft menu button by default.do you have any idea.