# Custom Navigation bar and option button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

How to set navigation bar in android and how to add option button on navigation bar ?

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080484/weird-options-menu-button-in-navigation-bar-android-4-0

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("menu");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if (menuDialog == null) {
        menuDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Dialog_Fullscreen);
        menuDialog.setContentView(menuView);
        menuDialog.show();
    } else {
        menuDialog.show();
    }
    return false;
}
```